# How to use electron with better-sqlite3?

Tags: electron, electron-forge, better-sqlite3

We have an electron application with better-sqlite3. It is using electron-webpack with better-sqlite3. Now I have to upgrade the application's packages because they are back from 2020. The only problem with that is that installing better-sqlite3 has its quirks. I had to downgrade my node version and use python 2.7.3 to install it successfully.
Are there any electron experts that used to deal with better-sqlite3? I would be so thankful if someone could help. It would also be nice to upgrade the react versions with that.

I also tried to build the app from scratch with electron forge. The problem with that was that you could only use the dialog from the main process and not in a react component. I also tried using sqlite-electron instead of better-sqlite3 but it is significantly slower and doesn't return column names when doing a simple query.

Is there a modern working solution for electron, react and better-sqlite3?

What would you guys do if you were in my shoes? Thank you in advance!